# While scroll the swiftUI list, cell's task modifier wasn't called. How to fix？

Tags: ios, swiftui, ios16

I have written a **AsyncImgView** with **swiftui**, and used in a list cell.

AsyncImgView use task modifier to download Img from cache or net when it appears, before iOS16 everything is ok, but in **iOS16** I found that while I **scroll the list** the new cell's **AsyncImgView doesn't call task modifier**, so new AsyncImageView won't download Img unless touch it again. And I found some other UI independent modifier has same problem.

I had tried call download func in body instead of using in task modifier, it works, but I don't think it's a good idea.

Anyone has any idea?

**Demo code:**

when scroll list, cann't print all cell name in task modifier

```
struct TaskDemo: View {
    var models: [TaskModel] = {
        var m = [TaskModel]()
        for idx in 0...99 {
            m.append(TaskModel(id: idx))
        }
        return m
    }()
    var body: some View {
        List(models){model in
            TaskCell(name: model.name)
                .frame(height: 100)
        }
    }
}

struct TaskModel: Identifiable {
    var id: Int
    var name: String { String(id) }
}

struct TaskCell: View {
    @State var name: String
    var body: some View{
            Text(name)
            .task {
                print("task default modifier \(Thread.current) \(name)")
            }
    }
}
```

the pic can show that I scroll to 31 cell but only print the first 17 cells' name
[image]

Comment: show a minimal reporducible code example,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example not the bits of code that you are showing us. 
      In particular, show the code for, and explain `imgContent`, similarly is `loadCachedImg()` 
      an async function? If not why not use `.onAppear{...}`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Already update code.`loadCachedImg()` is not the reason, the reason is `task{}` wasn't called, `onAppear{}` and `onReceive` also have the same problem. @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: your code seems to work for me (the print is executed), on macos 13 Ventura, using xcode 14.1-beta, target macCatalyst and ios-16.
Tested on real devices, not Previews. It may be different on older systems.

Comment: The problem first happen on real device(iPhone8 iOS16.0) before, then test again on simulator. Xcode14.0, macOS 12.6. maybe need to update macOS and Xcode?  
 by the way, how is your scrolling speed. I scroll fast @workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: with `.task{...}` if I scroll fast there are times when the `print` does not show.
 If I use `.onAppear{..}` it seems to print all expected values.

Comment: well, on my side, `.onAppear{}` has the same problem. However, Thanks for your help.@workingdogsupportUkraine

Comment: I see a mistake. `@State var name` should be `let name`

Comment: @malhal Maybe it's a mistake `@State var name`, but it's not the reason of this problem, I tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because `List` creates and updates `UICollectionViewCell`s and it reuses them. So when you scroll, the cell is not disappearing and re-appearing it is simply being shifted around the screen. Since task runs when the view appears it doesn't happen because the cell already appeared and was just moved. Clearly SwiftUI is doing some optimisation here however you can override it with the use of `.equatable` and `Equatable`, e.g.

```
struct TaskModel: Identifiable {
    let id: Int
    var name: String { String(id) }
}

struct TaskDemo: View {
    let models = (0...99).map { TaskModel(id: $0) }

    var body: some View {
        List(models) { model in
            TaskCell(name: model.name)
                .equatable()
                .frame(height: 100)
        }
    }
}

struct TaskCell: View, Equatable {
    let name: String

    var body: some View{
            Text(name)
            .task {
                print("task default modifier \(Thread.current) \(name)")
            }
    }
}
```

Note: before iOS 16 List used `UITableViewCell`

Note2: I believe this workaround doesn't work when using Sections that contain the same cells.

Comment: Thanks it help me to fix the problem.

Comment: How did you end up fixing it?